# Entitlements mismatch error - where to get details?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've got the infamous

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

error, and there have been other questions about it, but the message doesn't seem t have enough detail to fix it, or to explain the cause. It says

> The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing
>   Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning
>   profile

but which entitlements file, and which provisioning profile?

My app was fine, it's on the store, but one day I got this error and am completely stuck ever since. I don't know what I did!

My app has a main iOS app, a Now app, a watch kit app, and a watch kit extension, each with an entitlements file (I use an application group to share data). All the files have the same content. And of course, each of these targets have build settings with a code signing section. The provisioning profile is set to automatic on these. But which profile is it using?

Over time, various provisioning profiles have built up, some made by me, some made by XCode. I've got "XC" prefix ones for each target made by XCode, "iOS Team Provisioning Profile" ones, and ones I created and named. So I don't know which profiles are being used. When I set specific ones, it doesn't seem to help.

Finally when you look in the profiles, they say enabled services are "App Groups, Game Center, In-App Purchase", the first is necessary, the latter two aren't but seem to be automatic.

So. Where can I look for details about what is being matched against what, and what to change to fix this? It seems this error frustrates many, I hope Apple can add some details to this error. For example, didn't XCode, when you set the code signing settings to "Automatic" used to add which one it was using, like "Automatic (myapp development profile)"?

Comment: I have the same issue. Super irritating. Did you find a solve?

Answer (score 0):

In your General if your bundle identifier and signing identity(Debug) and signing identity(Release)  contains different provisioning profile then you get this error so make sure you have entered the same provisioning profile on both the places and  always check yes to Automatically manage sigining